# ios5 storyboard: instantiate multiple viewcontrollers in one container view controller

Tags: objective-c

I have a tab bar controller at the root level.

Let's say one of the tab brings up a "MainContainerViewController".

In this "MainContainerViewController", essentially I need another 'tab bar' of 5 options below. Obviously I cannot have two tab bar in a project so I put a tool bar below "MainControllerViewController".

Each of the 5 options should show an independent view controller while keeping the toolbar below.

Before ios5 and storyboard, what i will do is to alloc+initWithNib for the 5 view controllers, and then add the appropriate viewcontroller's view into the maincontainerviewcontroller's view when a button is clicked.

But now with ios5 and storyboard, what should I do since for all these 5 view controllers I have no more nib? How should I connect in the storyboard so that the "mainviewcontroller" will instantiate these 5 view controllers and I will be able to add their view later.?

Hopefully someone can understand my question...

p/s: 
I do not want the 5 view controllers to be "pushed" into the mainviewcontroller... That's because I do not want the navigation effect and I want to keep the toolbar below always. 
Therefore I only want to add the subviews into MainContainerViewController's view...

Answer (score 1):

hi I have found the specific solution to what I need.

basically what i m looking for is sth like this:

```
UIStoryboard *aStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
childControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[aStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"0"],
[aStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1"],
[aStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"2"],
[aStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"3"],
nil];
```

Thanks for your help though, hector.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to create more ViewControllers (5 is what you need) INSIDE your Storyboard and connect them using segues.

I learned the new flow of creating application following the new storyboard way using this Apple Tutorial -> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

This one is also good -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1